# Disallow JavaScript from closing window in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to debug an issue where the browser disappears after refreshing a particular page. I want to see if I can eliminate JavaScript as being the cause of this issue.

Does IE have an equivalent to the Firefox configuration option `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows`?

Comment: On windows you can use fiddler to deal with this sort of issues http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling and this was the closest thing I could find, but I do not know if it also prevents JavaScript from closing windows.

[Prevent Users from Closing the Browser or Explorer Windows](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/prevent-users-from-closing-the-browser-or-explorer-windows/)

**Edit:** You can use the *onbeforeunload* event to see if the page is triggering some sort of close event.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "The browser is about to close this window, are you sure?"; // Will appear as a confirmation box
};
```